# Trouble getting GetMeaningfulUseVDTReport results with HealthVault SDK

Tags: c#, healthvault

I have been working on an application that sends DOPU (drop-off/pick-up) requests for CCD documents via Health.  Creating the DOPU requests and getting the corresponding token generated by HealthVault work fine.

There are two SDK methods I am using to get Meaningful Use report data right now:

1. `OfflineWebApplicationConnection.GetMeaningfulUseTimelyAccessDOPUDocumentReport` gets me all the DPU requests sent.  This works fine, this always gives me the correct DOPU requests (with data/time stamp, token, and application ID).
2. The other is `OfflineWebApplicationConnection.GetMeaningfulUseVDTReport` method.  This is the one causing problems.  No matter what date range I set (a week, a month, Datetime.MinValue to DateTime.MaxValue), I always get no results.  No matter how many time I go into my HV account, to view and download my connection DOPU documents.  That SDK method still gives me no results.

I have also tried using CCD extension XML when sending a CCD to **specifically** set the *patient-id* and *entry-date*.  Again, this doesn't affect my report results.

Does anyone else with more experience than I have with the Meaningful User methods in the SDK that I, have any suggestions on why I get nothing at all, ever, for the `OfflineWebApplicationConnection.GetMeaningfulUseVDTReport` call?

Here is some sample code that I am using to run the reports (some of the commented lines are just me trying different date ranges).  I can also post snippets of code showing how I am sending the DOPU requests, even though that all seems to be behaving as expected.

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var applicationId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationId"];
            var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HealthServiceUrl"];
            var connection = new OfflineWebApplicationConnection(new Guid(applicationId), url, Guid.Empty/* offlinePersonId */);

            Console.WriteLine("\nGetMeaningfulUseTimelyAccessDOPUDocumentReport");
            //var receipts = connection.GetMeaningfulUseTimelyAccessDOPUDocumentReport(new DateRange(new DateTime(2014, 11, 19), new DateTime(2014, 12, 19)));
            var receipts = connection.GetMeaningfulUseTimelyAccessDOPUDocumentReport(new DateRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue));
            //var receipts = connection.GetMeaningfulUseTimelyAccessDOPUDocumentReport(new DateRange(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-12), DateTime.UtcNow));

            foreach (var receipt in receipts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2}", receipt.AvailableDate, receipt.PackageId, receipt.Source));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nGetMeaningfulUseVDTReport");
            //var activities = connection.GetMeaningfulUseVDTReport(new DateRange(new DateTime(2000, 12, 3), new DateTime(2014, 12, 10)));
            //var activities = connection.GetMeaningfulUseVDTReport(new DateRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue));
            var activities = connection.GetMeaningfulUseVDTReport(new DateRange(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-12), DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1)));

            foreach (var activity in activities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(activity.PatientId);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

**Update 1**
Tried the sample Meaningful Use web application that MS had on codeplex.  Used it with our application ID/credentials.  Well, it worked.  Not sure what is different, at least, so far.

**Update 2**
So I have tried many other real CCDs (in our PPE enrionment, immediately deleting them when done) including test CCDs.  I even set up the ConnectPackage in my app to behave the same as the test application from MS.  No matter what I send, I get know Meaningful Use VDT data for the CCDs.  The test CCD in the MS test application, however, works.

**Update 3**
Tried sending CCDs through the MS test application.  Again, it sends and I can connect to an HV account with no problem.  I get no VDT data, no matter the date range used.  Maybe there is an issue with our CCDs?